# Function in SQL to diff values from 2 different tables and put the value to a third table

Tags: c#, sql

I have three tables (table1, table2, table3).

In table1 I have different values (some of them are same but it's ok), in table2 I also have different values (some of them are same but it's ok).

Now I want to create a function which is going to sum the same values of table1 sum the values from table2 and do a diff between the same values and insert that value in a specific column of table3.

**table1**:

```
KodikosBarcode  total
1                14
2                18
```

**table2**:

```
KodikosBarcode  total
1                 1
2                 2
```

**table3** should have to be like this

```
KodikosBarcode  total
1                 13
2                 16
```

Can someone help?

then table3 will have
**table3:** 
KodikosBarcode  total
1                 13
2                 16
3                  1

Comment: Edit your question and provide (1) sample data; (2) desired results; (3) a tag for the database you are working on.

Comment: Your example data does not match your description of what you want it to do... Have a look at the help for posting: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I've edited the initial post to make the table structure clear - the original poster had laid them out but not added formatting indentation.

Comment: What's the expected result if you add a barcode 3 row to table1, and a barcode 4 row to table2?

Comment: then table3 will have**table3** should have to be like this

    KodikosBarcode total
    1                 13
    2                 16

Comment: It's usually best not to *store* that which can be *calculated*. You could create a *view* based on tables 1 & 2 and querying that view would *always be correct*.

Answer (score 0):

Like this? (If MSSQL) but hopefully you get the idea anyway...

```
INSERT Table3
(SomeColumn)
SELECT 
(SELECT Sum(SomeColumnFromTable1) FROM Table1) - 
(SELECT Sum(SomeColumnFromTable2) FROM Table2)
```

To update you would do a similar thing;

```
UPDATE Table3
SET SomeColumn = (SELECT 
    (SELECT Sum(SomeColumnFromTable1) FROM Table1) - 
    (SELECT Sum(SomeColumnFromTable2) FROM Table2))
WHERE (whatever row you want to update... you didn't tell us)
```

Comment: this query creates a new row and puts the values.i want to update every different value.

Comment: @VagelisDaldavanis ... yes because you asked "put that value in a specific column of table3" and this is what my answer does... Please clarify your question if that is not what you want...

Comment: i want to update every row.sorry for my writing but I'm a begginer in stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

for SQL Server:

```
insert into table 3
    (
        KodikosBarcode
        , Diff_Value
    )
select
    t1.KodikosBarcode
    t1.total - t2.total
from 
    table1 as t1
        inner join table2 as t2
            on t2.KodikosBarcode = t1.KodikosBarcode
```

This assumes that you only want the difference between rows where the bar code exists in both tables.

If you're doing an update to existing rows in the target table, you would use:

```
update t3 set
    t3.total = t1.total - t2.total
from table3 as t3
    inner join table1 as t1
        on t1.KodikosBarcode = t3.KodikosBarcode
    inner join table2 as t2
        on t2.KodikosBarcode = t3.KodikosBarcode
```